# d3.js How to draw a Force-Directed Graph with nodes grouped by circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm doing a community detection project,

I use d3.js to demonstrate the result of the algorithm.

By now I'm using colors on nodes to indicate different community they belongs, like this:

[image]

Since the result is gonna be printed on a paper(black and white only, you know), it's not a good choice to use different colors.

So I would like to draw a graph like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

**I just want to group the nodes with circles.**

**Can anyone help me? Thank You!**

Comment: Compute the [convex hull](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341699) for each group of nodes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks, it seems helpful, feel free to give out a specific answer.